# Problem with subscribe and template ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subscribe, ionic5

I am trying to display an image from firebase storage as below:

In my component :

```
    findImg(img) {
    this.storage.ref('/img/' + img).getDownloadURL().subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log(result);
      }
    )
```

In my template :

```
    <ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>La gamme : {{collectionName}}</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let pro of product | async">
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>{{pro.name}}</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <p>{{pro.img}}</p>
      <div *ngIf="findImg(pro.img)"></div>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

pro.img is the name of the field "img" in my database for my product and the name of his picture in storage too.

Everything works except the div with ngIf. In the console, the result is good but displayed ad infinitum, and Chrome crashes. I don't understand why the loop never ends.

[the bug in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yJqM.png)

Comment: Just 2 products in my database

Comment: It could be because everytime change detection is run this method `findImg(pro.img)` is being called which is probably why you are getting those messages in the console. Can you try to replace that by a variable?

Comment: I understand what you say, for example findImg($myVariable) ? But how can i get this variable ? i'm sorry but i'm junior :) that supposes to modify my code but i don't now how to isolate this data.

Comment: No. Do the subscription of `product` in the component itself and while you do that calculate the image and store it in an array. On the template just iterate over the array.

Comment: ok i will try tomorrow and make a comeback @NicholasK (depending on my level :) )

Comment: @NicholasK I tried that (in second post).

Answer (score 0):

I tried another solution, get the name and url of the image and send them in an array :

```
tab: Array<any> = [[], []];

async getImage() {
 return this.storage.ref('img').listAll().subscribe( result => {
  result.items.forEach(imageRef => {
    this.image = imageRef.name;
    this.refImage = imageRef.getDownloadURL().then( url => {
      console.log('My URL : ' + url);
      return this.url = url;
    });
    this.tab.push([this.image, this.url]);
  });
  console.log(this.tab);
});
}
```

The first one console.log works but the last not. The first value of this.tab appears but the second is undefined. I think i have a problem with getDownloadUrl() and his then but i don't know how to fix it.